# Two neural networks simultaneous optimization

Tags: optimization, neural-network

I have two neural networks, ann1 and ann2. These are in a sequential form. I have matrix X as input for ann1 and y1 as output of ann1. Then a predetermined function of f(y1) as input for ann2. The output af ann 2 is y2 that can be compared to vector y to make cost function. The object is minimization of this cost function. There is no data to be compared to y1. So my model is like this:
X-> ann1-> y1-> f(y1)-> ann2-> y2-> cost_function.

So the problem is the necessary transformation f(y1) in the middle of two network. Now how can I optimise these two networks simultaneously in a package like tensor flow? Thanks

I have no idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to make sure that your transformation `f` itself is differentiable, or that in general df/dx is not 0. In a package like tensorflow this simply means putting together  f itself with tensorflow ops. For example imagine f(x) := 3*x + 1

then you would literally do in tf

```
output1 = nn1(x)
output2 = nn2(3*output1 + 1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean((output2 - target)**2)
```

What if f is non differentiable? For example it is a nearest neighbour lookup or something like this? Well then the answer is "this cannot be done by pure engineering practise" and it requires more open ended investigation on a research front, seeking help of straight through estimators, stochastic computation graphs, RL etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The function f is linear function so it is differentiable. So how can I train two ann models simultaneously?

Comment: yes. You can think of it as effectively one big neural network, with a hard coded, non traninable layer in the middle